# AjentiV Mail Server Setup

Tags: linux, email, exim, courier

AjentiV recently added support for mail server/ mail forward. I have been trying to get mail working on my domain but I have never set up courier or exim. I was wondering if anyone has instructions on Ajenti V mail setup.

Answer (score 6):

You can install ajenti-v-mail by doing the following

install basic ajenti-v-mail package, run: `apt-get install ajenti-v-mail`

Exim and Courier mail will automatically be installed.

Afterthat you can creat an email address test@example.com using the Mailbox button in the Mail section of the ajenti admin panel.

This is the default configuration generated for a new email account.

- Username: test@example.com
- Password: your password
- SMTP server: server's address
- IMAP server: server's address
- Ports: default ones (TLS SMTP and IMAPS if you have configured TLS for mail Ajenti V).

I hope it helps

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to configure a catchall email account with Ajenti?

Comment: When I try to install it I get this warning: "WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!". Why is it?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what @Beaudinn said.
When I configured my email client and tried to retrieve my email, it failed with "No Inbox" or something.
I had to execute `maildirmake` in the user folder created in `/var/vmail/`

```
# cd /var/vmail/test@example
# maildirmake
```

With `exim -i test@example` you can send an email test after writing the body (you have to end the text input with Ctrl+D the `EOF` character).
And from the same terminal you can check your inbox with `telnet yourdomain imap` (look for some tutorials on google).
Still, I can't receive email when it's sent from another server. I'm still trying to figure out which settings Ajenti tried to set.

--EDIT--

About my problem about not receiving emails:
`netstat -tulpn` showed that a `sendmail` service was using the port 25 and not exim.
Uninstalling sendmail and restarting exim did the work.
Centos6 Clean VPS